# How to pass the key variable to eventListener function defined elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Normally when you add eventlisteners you'd do:

```javascript
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){// get e.keyCode here});
```

But what if I defined a function somewhere else and just wanna pass the function as a variable? It'd look something like this:

```javascript
input.addEventListener('keyup', func);
```

How do I pass in the `e` as an argument here (or any other arguments in general)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a named function which passes `e`. `e` is the Event Object all event handlers pass as default. An event handler is the function called when a registered event is triggered. An event is registered when it is the first parameter of an event listener:

```
.addEventListener('keyup', eventHandler)
```

OR a onevent property

```
.onkeyup = eventHandler;
```

OR a inline attribute (don't use this one, it's [no good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these))

```
<input onkeyup='eventHandler(e)'>
```

In the example below, **A** is an anonymous function and **B** is the same as **A** but has a named function as event handler.

```js
const inputA = document.querySelector('.A');
const inputB = document.querySelector('.B');

// Anonymous event handler
inputA.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  console.log(e.key);
});

// Named event handler
inputB.addEventListener('keyup', keyHandler);

function keyHandler(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
}
```

```html
<label>A: <input class='A'></label><br>
<label>B: <input class='B'></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a parameter for the function. The syntax is the same for named functions as for anonymous function expressions.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', func);
function func(e /* event object */ ){
  console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

```html
Type something here: <input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not explicitly pass it

```js
function func(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}


document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', func)
```

```html
<input id='input'>
```